# How can my applications be using a total of 1.44 TB?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I have a Samsung S4 16 GB with android 5.0 stock ROM, and when I check my user data it says that my programs are using up 1.44 TB. How can this even be possible?

Screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what happens if you click on apps?

Comment: If I press applications I'm taken to a list of all programs that are installed and how much memory they use.

Comment: I meant so you can see how much space they are using

Comment: But what good will that do? Either my applications are actually using that much memory which sounds pretty weird, or there is some bug in the output of how much memory that is actually used.

Comment: Then you can see if there is an individual app using this amount of space

Comment: No one is, it is the combined usage of all the applications.

Comment: So, _all_ the applications seemingly report inflated usage?! Try the [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage) app to see how storage is really allocated. Do you have a (dodgy?!) external memory card?